# Why would this cause an error on subsequent runs?

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

I have the follow code in a VB6 app that builds an Excel spreadsheet:

```
wrksh.Range("F4:F" & rn).Select
With Selection
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("J5"), Unique:=True
End With
```

The first time through, it works great. If I delete the spreadsheet, run it a second time without shutting down the program, I get error '91', "Object variable or with block variable not set".

Any ideas why, and how I can fix it?

Comment: try the code in my answer below, and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `wrksh` is fully qualified to a valid sheet in your workbook (defined as `Worksheet`). `rn` is a numeric value, representing the last row of your `Range` (defind as `Long`). And last, `ActiveSheet` is the same sheet as `wrksh` sheet, then the code below should work for you:

```
With wrksh.Range("F4:F" & rn)
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wrksh.Range("J5"), Unique:=True
End With
```

Comment: All your assumptions are correct, and your suggestion DID fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Obfuscated also a broken clock shows the correct time twice a day :)  You're welcome